# How to display values from my firebase collection?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

HTML Code which attempts to show elements from the firebase.

```
<div class= "sentMessages" *ngFor= "let item of snapshot">
  {{item.timestamp.toDate() | date:"medium"}}
  {{item.name}}
  {{item.message}}
</div>
```

This is the app.component.ts. This attempts to get the collection from the database.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ChatApp';
  name: string;
  color: string = "#127bdc";
  message: string = "";
  messages: any;
  snapshot: any


  constructor (private db: AngularFirestore){
    this.name = "";
    this.messages =db.collection('messages');
  }
  async addMessage(){
 
      const res = await this.db.collection('messages').add({
        name : this.name,
        color : this.color,
        message : this.message,
        timestamp: new Date()  });

        this.snapshot = await this.messages.get();

  }
}
```

When addMessage runs upon the user clicking enter it correctly saves to the firebase database, but it doesn't print out what is currently in the database.

Answer (score 0):

read more about angular change detection

solution :

```
  async addMessage(){

  const res = await this.db.collection('messages').add({
    name : this.name,
    color : this.color,
    message : this.message,
    timestamp: new Date()  });

    const a = await this.messages.get();
    this.snapshot= [...a]
}
```